# Latex with side heading and all headings in same line

Tags: lists

How to create something this in latex?

[image]

Comment: Where is the typical text block boundary in this image? It may affect the type of solution that is given.

Comment: The text block is completely filled on the page. Above that there is a subsection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set both elements in a list - the first inside a `description` and the last inside an `enumerate`. An adjustment to `\makelabel` is made to set each `description` item with a trailing `\hfill:`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{2}% Just for this example

\section{Specific Requirements}

\subsection{Functional Requirement Specification}

\subsubsection{User Login}

% Style taken from example in section 11 Samples of enumitem documentation
% http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem
\begin{description}[leftmargin=3cm, style=sameline]
  % Update description label (let to \makelabel) to set the font and add \hfill: to end
  \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{\normalfont#1\hfill:}%
  \item[Use case name]
  User Login

  \item[Objective]
  Used to log in an existing profile.

  \item[Priority]
  High

  \item[Precondition]
  User is not logged in to a profile, input profile exists in database, user password matches profile

  \item[Postconditions]
  Page data is appropriate for selected profile

  \item[Flow of events]
  \begin{enumerate}[nosep,leftmargin=1.5em]
    \item Basic flow
    
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*]
      \item User enters the username and password in the text box and then clicks on the Login button.
      \item An animated loading bar is shown while the authentication of the user profile takes place.
      \item The Webpage is updated for the user profile.
    \end{enumerate}
    
    \item Alternative Flow 1
    
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*]
      \item In case of invalid username or invalid password or mismatched password, an error message is shown and it is redirected to the previous page.
      \item Software disposes the dialog box
      \item Software places cursor at beginning position of the editor
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ```
\newcommand{\leftid}[2][8em]{\par\noindent\makebox[120pt][r]{\makebox[#1][l]{#2\hfill:~}}\ignorespaces}
 ```

can I change the command like this to make it align according to the default alignment? Currently it's left-aligned

Comment: @AanandS: That will not allow for proper wrapping of the text that have long lines of text. This is why I asked about what the text block looks like; it will give an indication if the "left ids" are jutting into the margin, or contained within the text block. Just stating that the text block is completely filled doesn't seem to match the image, as there would be lots of whitespace to the left of the list shown in the picture. So, please provide some more context of the entire page. Can you do that?

Comment: I have updated the question with the full page

Comment: @AanandS: Updated the answer. In the future, can you please provide sufficient detail *as well as* a minimal example that the community can work with? That would be appreciated.